# Android 4.3 incompatibility issues with Galaxy Nexus and my own application

Tags: installation, manifest, incompatibility, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have just uploaded an android application on play store for alpha testing and below are its aapt dump badging details. It shows that this application is incompatible with my Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3. I have been testing this application on this phone itself. 
I cant seem to figure out what am I doing wrong. My other phone which is android 4.2.2 seems to be compatible.

```
./aapt  dump badging ~/Desktop/MyApp.apk 
package: name='com.example.MyApp' versionCode='4' versionName='1.4'
sdkVersion:'14'
targetSdkVersion:'18'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission:'android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES'
application-label:'MyApp'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable/icon.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable/icon.png'
application: label='MyApp' icon='res/drawable/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.example.MyApp.MyActivity'  label='' icon=''
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.location','requested a location access permission'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps','requested android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.network'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.location.network','requested android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION permission'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait','one or more activities have specified a portrait orientation'
main
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'ca' 'da' 'fa' 'ja' 'nb' 'be' 'de' 'af' 'bg' 'th' 'fi' 'hi' 'vi' 'sk' 'uk' 'el' 'nl' 'pl' 'sl' 'tl' 'am' 'in' 'ko' 'ro' 'ar' 'fr' 'hr' 'sr' 'tr' 'cs' 'es' 'ms' 'et' 'it' 'lt' 'pt' 'hu' 'ru' 'zu' 'lv' 'sv' 'iw' 'sw' 'en_GB' 'zh_CN' 'pt_BR' 'es_US' 'pt_PT' 'zh_TW'
densities: '160' '240' '320' '480'
```

Comment: Hey, I am facing this same issue.Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could call PackageManager.hasSystemFeature() and check if all the features listed in uses-feature by appt are supported in the Nexus with Android 4.3